# Return value from a stored procedure with EF5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I am having trouble capturing the return value from a stored procedure with EF5

my SP code is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckLogin] 
@clubId int,
@userName nvarchar(150),
@password nvarchar(50),
@result INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (
            SELECT ID FROM 
            Users 
            WHERE clubId=@clubId 
            AND UserName=@userName 
            AND Password=@password)
BEGIN
    SET @result = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @result = 0
END

SELECT @result
END
```

I am calling the in C# with

```
int ok;
        using (var ctx = new ClubEntities())
        {
            var result = new ObjectParameter("result", typeof(double));

            var a = ctx.CheckLogin(model.ClubId, model.UserName, model.Password, result);
            ok = Convert.ToInt32(result.Value);
        }
```

The value of ok is always 0

I have check the stored procedure in management studio and that gives me the correct result

can anyone advise where I am going wrong

thanks

Comment: Why are you defining your ObjectParameter as double when the SP returns an INT?

Comment: I was trying a different type to see if it made a difference, the result is the same if the objectparamter is set as int

Comment: Are you sure your model.ClubId, model.UserName, and model.Password are populated correctly? If you debug and verify their values, does executing the stored procedure directly using those values result in 1?

Comment: What's the value of `a`? You don't need either the output variable or the return variable.